# I don't understand macros

Tags: c++, macros

I can't understand those macros in c++... I have heard from many videos and people that their job is to replace their name with something that you have defined them.
For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#define say std::cout<<

int main()
{
    say "Hello World";
}
```

But I have seen many codes that do that

```
#include <iostream>
#define say
```

If you don't understand what I am saying they skip the second part of the definition...why?

Comment: Note: You rarely *need* macros. In most cases they are a bad/wrong tool for the job and you should just be writing a function instead.

Comment: The first code is legal, but very poor taste

Answer (score 1):

The statement `#define say std::cout<<` is a macro. `macro name` is `say` and `macro body` is `std::cout<<`. so when `preprocessor` will see the *macro name* it replaces with *macro body*.

At preprocessor stage your code looks like this

```
int main() {
 std::cout<< "Hello World";
 return 0;
}
```

just run `g++ -Wall -E test.cpp` and check yourself.

**Case 2 :** `#define say`

Here there is no `macro body` so it replaces with nothing. At preprocessor stage your code looks like this

```
int main() {
 "Hello World";
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might want to add to your answer the other part of his question, where he asks what `#define say` alone means.

Comment: that means there is no macro-body so it replaces with white-spaces I think.

Comment: The second case is  commonly used so you can test it with an `#ifdef`.

Comment: yes I agree @NeilButterworth to check if `macro` is defined or not, use `#ifdef`